# Hidden disk usage in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hyper-v

I have an exFAT-formatted disk which I put some hyper-V VMs on. One of the VHDs was dynamically sized so it would just eat up more disk space as it was being used. I was doing something in the VM that used a ton of disk space, so it ended up using the whole drive and running out of space which crashed the VM. As I went to go clear out some space for it to run again, I noticed that the files in there did not add up to the space marked as free. I have now even moved the original vhdx off of it and there's still a 60GB deficit, even though the drive is basically empty at this point. You can see the deficit in the two screenshots: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdJV.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqtjx.jpg).

So far I have tried:

- checking if there's a pagefile or hiberfil there, which there is not
- rebooting (in case it was some sort of cache)
- running chkdsk /F, which did not do anything, but curiously reports there being 2 more files than TreeSize, and reports the correct amount of disk usage in that number of files (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7PI8.png))
- running chkdsk /R, which actually reports there being corruption and restoring some more files, but they are just empty (the FOUND.00X directories). If I run it again, the same thing happens again. New FOUND.00X directories which are just empty.
- running Disk Cleanup, but there is nothing reported that accounts for the deficit

All to no avail. It's possible the hyper-V thing is totally unrelated but this is behavior I've never seen normally in windows which is why I mention that. Or it is an exFAT thing, I am not sure.

Also, reformatting the drive is a fine solution in this case, since I have already cleared it, but I am worried about having to do this in the future in a drive which has lots of other data on it, if it is some sort of hyper-V thing.

Comment: The two are probably unrelated : Hyper-V and disk corruption. I don't know, and we'll probably never know, what caused the corruption, but it was likely caused by a lot of disk and file-table activity as the file expanded. As a last check before formatting, check the SMART attributes of the disk. If you don't have an app for that, use [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/?PageSpeed=noscript). If you wish us to have a look, add these attributes to your post.

Comment: Do not use exFAT, as that's that's likely the issue - instead, reformat as NTFS, and the issue should immediately go away. exFAT uses insanely large allocation unit sizes [32KB, 64KB, etc.] versus the 4KB NTFS uses, and creates more problems than it's worth, like this. Here's how that works: 64KB Allocation unit size will always use 64KB of storage space, regardless if the data housed in that space is 1KB, 3KB, or 63KB, so a 1KB file will take up 64KB of space, multiply this by thousands, and it results in exponential amounts of inaccessible and wasted storage space

Comment: @JW0914 interesting, but that is not the issue here, is it? There is a clear difference in the number of files reported by checkdisk and the number of files visible in e.g. TreeSize. So I guess it is actually corrupted and those 2 files are taking up all the space. Anyway, I will format it as per your suggestion, thanks

Comment: @JuliendeC I could very well be wrong then =] _(if I am, I'll delete these comments =])_ Unless there's a specific reason for not using NTFS, even then ext3/ext4 could be used and mounted through WSL or Paragon's [LinuxFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/), NTFS should always be used on Windows. Rule of thumb when choosing Allocation Unit sizes: anything over 4KB, divide by two (exponentially) to determine actual storage space that will be accessible - e.g.  worst case scenario with a 100GB partition:  4KB: 100GB | 32KB: 12.5GB | 64KB: 6.25GB | 128KB: 3.125GB

Comment: I see. I don't have a good reason for not using NTFS, no. I think I put it as exFAT because I was using the drive for [YUMI](https://pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and i think that was the recommended option or something like that. Then I just stared putting other files there cause it was free space.

Comment: @JuliendeC exFAT does have benefits for SD cards used in cameras and some phones since hi-res photos and videos are large single files, and does serve a purpose with USB drives if needing to house a file >4GB or for partitions >2TB , but other than that, if needing a non-NTFS filesystem accessible from both Windows and BSD/Linux/Mac, I prefer Large FAT32 _(requires a third party program in Windows to format, such as [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/))_ or ext3/ext4 for USB drives if NTFS can't be used. IMHO exFAT is a purpose-built filesystem that unless needing it, really should be avoided.

Comment: If your VHD is expanded, deleting files alone doesn't reduce it.. You'll need to run the compact disk option in the VM's storage settings..