# Security of an encrypted partition in a flash drive

Tags: partitioning, security, encryption, usb-flash-drive, bitlocker

I have a flash drive that I carry with me everywhere in a keyring for convenient access to personal files on other people's computers. In the past, these flash drives tend to get lost as they break off from the key ring. As the flash drive contains personal files, it makes me feel uneasy to think that someone might have access to them.

To counter this, I decided to get a 256GB flash drive (cheap these days), and partition it into 2 roughly equally-sized partition. The first partition is regularly formatted with exFAT, while the other one is formatted with exFAT and then encrypted with Bitlocker. The idea here is that I would put my personal files only in the encrypted partition. The unencrypted partition can be used for non-personal files that I wouldn't care to be exposed. My choice of using Bitlocker instead of Veracrypt comes down to compatibility: it just works on Windows and most Linux distros without needing to install additional software (not on Mac and Android unfortunately, but it's the best I can do, (unrelated but if you have a better idea let me know!)).

Meanwhile, I have recently been reading about the shred command and its limitations on flash devices. Specifically there's a study paper showing that using the Gutmann method (which is employed in the shred command) still allows people to recover 71.9% of a file's contents, which sounds like it is not particularly effective. This made me doubt the effectiveness of my encrypted partition.. Does the same reason that shred isn't effective in USB flash drives also apply to encrypted partitions on consumer flash drives? Is my encrypted partition strategy fundamentally flawed due to the nature of how flash drives work, or for any other reason?

Note that my threat level is really to make it difficult for the average person or techie to read my personal info in the event I lose the flash drive. I am not trying to protect myself against state actors, corporate espionage, or targeted attacks. This question is mainly to understand the limitations of my method.

Comment: Good encryption makes shreds mostly meaningless. The contents of an encrypted folder are scrambled bits, which is also the "contents" of a shredded file. So long as the drive or partition are encrypted before you place any files on it, the only data written to that area will be the encrypted data. This should be plenty sufficient for keeping your files secure from all but the most determined attackers.

Comment: I don't see what shredding has to do with encryption. Also, where did read this: "Specifically there's a study paper showing that using the Gutmann method (which is employed in the shred command) still allows people to recover 71.9% of a file's contents"?

Comment: The encryption is secure. An alternative to BitLocker is Zip file encryption that can be read on almost *any* machine, Mac, Linux, Windows or Android -- handy when traveling.

Comment: Why are you worried about data recovery if you’re using BitLocker? Recovery with encrypted volumes is impossible. All volumes should be encrypted.

Comment: General FYI: Unless mainly storing extremely large single files on a partition, exFAT is an extremely storage inefficient filesystem to use due to its large allocation unit sizes _(it's really a purpose-built filesystem for cameras/video recorders where extremely large single files are the norm)_. Please see my comments under [this](https://superuser.com/q/1831465/529800) question for an in-depth explanation why.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I wouldn't recommend zip archives for this, for several reasons. First, the format is not designed for modification, so changing the contents may or may not be possible. Second, depending on the extractor in use, you may not be able to get at the contained files without first extracting them to decrypted format (and then having to worry about securely deleting the extracted copy). Third, a lot of zip implementations still use the old zip 2.0 encryption (aka "traditional" or "legacy" encryption), which is is breakable, although not trivial.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, 7-Zip, fairly common, includes AES256 encryption (yes, that could be better, but OK for casual use). As you state, this would not be suitable for "live" files, but for static personal files, e.g., backup of contacts, lists of credit cards (ever lose a wallet?), etc., it's good. And Zip has the advantage of not requiring additional software to access (e.g., Disklocker, for Linux, BitlockerGoMac for Mac OS).

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that recovering from an encrypted partition is impossible, but is this still the case if you can recover old writes due to the way flash memory works.. wouldn't that weaken the encryption? I think I should've summarized my question as this

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: AES has been part of the Zip format for a good couple years now. I don't think there are any programs left that only support the "Zip2.0" encryption.

Comment: @9a3eedi - Old writes are encrypted too, no? Moreover, old writes could only be recovered during a more advanced attack, you'd need chip-off recovery tools. And then still you'd only recover encrypted blobs in discarded sectors.

Comment: @9a3eedi - The entire volume is encrypted, all writes are encrypted, so any data restored would be random encrypted data. BitLocker with a TPM 2.0 is as secure as any encryption.

Comment: @u1686_grawity The AES option for zip encryption has been around for quite a while, but adoption is inconsistent at best. For example, I just tried using `zip -e` on Ubuntu and NetBSD systems, and both used the legacy encryption. In general, if the docs for the program you're using don't specifically say AES, it's probably still using legacy encryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Specifically there's a study paper showing that using the Gutmann method (which is employed in the shred command) still allows people to recover 71.9% of a file's contents

The Gutmann method was created for magnetic storage (HDDs), not for flash storage. (More specifically, it was created for MFM-type HDDs that were already obsolete by the time the method was *published.*)

> Does the same reason that shred isn't effective in USB flash drives also apply to encrypted partitions on consumer flash drives?

No, not at all.

The whole issue with 'shred' is about **deleting** data that has already been written, so it would only be relevant if you were a) activating BitLocker on a partition that already had data in it, or b) using manual file-level encryption, e.g. first saving plain files, then using a program like 'gpg' to encrypt them individually, then attempting to shred the original plain files.

Disk-level encryption *does not* work that way. It works by intercepting all sector write commands so that they get encrypted in-flight, and everything you do within the BitLocker volume is already encrypted by the time it reaches the storage. In other words, **there is nothing that would need to be deleted.** (That is, assuming you enabled BitLocker while the partition was still empty.)

So while it remains true that e.g. overwritten sectors physically remain in the flash storage for some time, that doesn't matter because those are all *encrypted* sectors – recovering them is useless unless the attacker already has the BitLocker decryption key anyway.

> Note that my threat level is really to make it difficult for the average person or techie to read my personal info in the event I lose the flash drive

Then you can kind-of ignore the 'shred' issues anyway, even if encryption wasn't in place.

The sector remapping that makes it difficult to "shred" data on flash storage is not done by the OS; it's done by the firmware of the storage device. Once a logical sector has been overwritten by the OS, only its new contents are visible to the OS – even though the old contents are still lingering in flash memory, they are *not* accessible to regular software in any way; it would take a recovery firm to reach them.

So when they say that data on flash drives remains recoverable after "shredding", they don't mean it's *easily* recoverable using Recuva or whatever other PC-based undeletion tool – they mean it's *technically* recoverable using expensive equipment that only a targeted attack would warrant.

Yes, if I lost a USB stick that used to have e.g. an SSH key that had been "shredded", I would still consider that key compromised, but it's not critical.

Comment: Great insight, thank you. Did not consider that it would require special physical hardware to read the shredded sectors, way beyond my threat level. What I was also wondering though... couldn't the recovered encrypted writes be somehow used to make the encryption breaking easier?

Comment: @9a3eedi: Well, not necessarily "millions of $" expensive – I suppose it might be a bit easier with a single-flash-chip USB stick than with SSDs – but it's still well above what any normal person would have, or have time and expertise to do. If there's a targeted attack of some kind, I can see it being a risk, but otherwise not really. (And as you continue using the flash drive that's got deleted data, eventually said physical sectors will get re-used to store new data anyway, so "lost a USB stick that had a file shredded 6 months ago" is less of an issue than "shredded yesterday".)

Comment: @9a3eedi: As for encryption breaking, I don't think that's an issue with AES-XTS that BitLocker uses, but you'd have to ask Crypto.SE for a more competent answer.